# How to set the state end in Java code MotionLayout

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I use MotionLayout

I want to manage the `@+id/end`  of the ConstraintSet in Java

for example

```
<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/item_c"
            motion:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            motion:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.3"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
            motion:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
    </ConstraintSet>
```

I want to set the "layout_constraintHorizontal_bias" value in Java on the switch

But I did not find a solution

what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ConstraintSet should have all the methods you need

```
MotionLayout ml = ...
ConstraintSet set = ml.getConstraintSet(R.id.end)
set.setHorizontalBias(R.id.widgetid, 0.4)
ml.updateState(R.id.end, set);
ml.rebuildScene();
```

If you are already in that state you might want to call

```
ml.updateStateAnimate(R.id.end,set,duration_in_ms);
```